# Webpack 4 without bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, concatenation, webpack-4

Simple question about webpack is it possible to have only concat and minify js file without code of webpack like this:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
```

i'm using extract-plugin, uglifyjsOption actually
i have multiple entry point on my webpack config like this

```
  entry: {
    account: [
       'js/lazyload.js',
       'matchmedia-polyfill/matchMedia.js',
       'jquery-ui/ui/core.js',
    ],layout:[ 
        'js/main.js',
        'js/form.js',
        'js/password-complexity',
]}
```

For each entry point i have my key and just want to have for each key the js only concat and minify without the module bundler of webpack.
I try [this](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/webpack/merge-multiple-javascript-into-single-file/) but it 's the same 
But i just want to concat and minify without bundler and need tio use Webpack and not gulp.

Thx for reply

Comment: No you can't. Webpack is a bundler, not a task runner. You MUST use gulp instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Webpack not to bundle files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096470/get-webpack-not-to-bundle-files)