# Webpack: transpile single from TS to JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle my app.

I need one specific file not be bundled but transpiled from typescript to javascript.
I dont want my imports to be bundled within the file.

For example if I have this typescript:

```
import { Service } from '@xyz/server';

class MyService extends Service {

constructor(dataPath) {
    super(dataPath);
  }
}
```

And it need to be transpiled to something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var server_1 = require("@xyz/server");
var MyService = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
__extends(MyService, _super);
function MyService(dataPath) {
    var _this = _super.call(dataPath) || this;
    return _this;
  }
return MyService;
}(server_1.Service));
```

Is there a way to do this with webpack or a webpack plugin?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to do it with webpack? When do you want this file to be transpiled?

Comment: Yes, I'm having a angular workspace and a custom node builder using webpack. I dont want to introduce another build step or another build config, therefore I "need" to use webpack for this task

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Webpack not to bundle files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096470/get-webpack-not-to-bundle-files)

Comment: How do you run webpack? Do you use an NPM script? You can add a pre or post script.

Comment: I dont use npm.
I'm calling a custom angular builder which uses webpack

@jabaa That question doesnt help me, I'm afraid. That is for creating seperate files instead of a bundle. But in that case webpack is still bundling all the dependencies within the files, which doesnt work in my case.

Comment: Just to make it clear. Webpack is a bundler that can call other tools. TypeScript is transpiler. You want to use Webpack to transpile your code, but not bundle it. I guess the cleanest solution is to add another build step.